# how to select node by text omitting node's childes' text

Tags: html, xpath

I have following code and I want to select label by text. I cannot use `//label[text()='some label']` or `//label[text()='other label']` because of two reasons:

- '//label[text()]' returns whole content of current node including
  span's content,
- white spaces.

I can use contains() function, but I really do NOT want to.

```
<label>
<span>some span</span>
  some label   
</label>

<label>
    other label
<span>other span</span>
</label>
```

SOLVED ???

```
//label[normalize-space(text()) = 'some label']
```

But why this strips internal nodes? I do not understand. According to http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space only white spaces should be removed, but not nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
//label[text()[normalize-space() = 'some label']]
```

then I hope you get what you want. It would however also select a label like

```
<label>text1<span>span text</span>some label</label>
```

Generally with mixed contents and several child text nodes with XPath 1.0 it is a bit difficult to cater for all possible cases, with XPath 2.0 you can do `//label[normalize-space(string-join(text(), '')) = 'some label']` which is more precise.

Comment: Which syntax is better: //label[text()[normalize-space() = 'some label']] vs //label[normalize-space(text()) = 'some label']

Comment: And what is far more important why normalize-space() trims internal nodes. This is crucial for me to understand.

Comment: You will need to explain what an "internal node" is and which behaviour you have noticed that you want to have explained when you say "normalize-space() trims internal nodes". The main difference between my suggestion `//label[text()[normalize-space() = 'some label']]` and your code is that my suggestion selects `label` elements which have (at least) a text child node whose normalized string value is `some label` why your attempt selects `label` elements where the first text child node has a normalized string value of `some label`. And with your sample the first text child node is white space.

Comment: Martin, I need to select label by text. Inside this label there is span node with its text - I need to ignore it. I use text(). I want to compare only text that is inside label, but not inside span. Therefore from label point of view, span is "internal node". I see that combination of `text()` and `normalize-space()` works fine. My question is why, `normalize-space()` ignores span's content? I don't understand this behavior. Can you explain it to me or point some documentation?

Comment: Martin, one more thing: why `//label[text()[normalize-space() = 'some label']]` selects label elements which have (at least) a text child node whose normalized string value is `some label` while `//label[normalize-space(text()) = 'some label']` not? I really want to understand. And thanks for your help:)

Comment: Well if you used `//label[normalize-space() = 'some span some label']` then the predicate would normalize the string value of the complete `label` element which is the concatenation of all text node descendants. I think that you lack an understanding of the type of nodes and the tree structure, a `label` parsed from `<label>  <span>some span</span> some label</label>` is parsed into a `label` element node with three child nodes, the first being a text node with white space, the second being a `span` element node and the third being a text node.